# How to Make Real Time Calculations in JavaScript Based on Form Fields?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first attempt with JavaScript, so apologies if this is particularly messy. I am trying to create a basic calculator which works out the 'research sample' (the sum under .forthBox.value) based on the values entered in boxes 1,2 and 3 once the calculate button is hit.

So far this works on js.fiddle, but not when I try to copy the code onto my website. Does anyone have any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Thanks,
Chris

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calc() {
    var form = document.getElementById('autoSumForm');
    one = form.firstBox.value;
    two = form.secondBox.value;
    three = form.thirdBox.value;
    form.fourthBox.value = ((((two) * (two)) * 0.25) / (((three) / 100) * ((three) / 100)) / (1 + (((two) * (two)) * 0.25) / (((three) / 100) * ((three) / 100) * (one))));
  }

  function stopCalc() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
</script>

<form id="autoSumForm">

  Population Size
  <input class="right" type=text name="firstBox" value="" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();">Confidence Level
  <select name="secondBox">
    <option value="1.645">90%</option>
    <option value="1.96">95%</option>
    <option value="2.576">99%</option>
  </select>

  Margin of Error
  <input class="right" type=text name="thirdBox" value="" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();">

  <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calc()" name="button">Sample Needed
  <input class="right" type=text name="fourthBox">

</form>
```

Comment: Really? It doesn't work on jsFiddle for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3x6g4L5e/. I get the same error as I do when I run it here `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstBox' of undefined`. You're also using the old legacy DOM notation of JavaScript which should be avoided.

Comment: I just took another look through and discovered I had pasted an older version here. I have updated my question with the latest version I have. This one works on jsBin, but not jsFiddle (only to add to my confusion. (jsBin: https://jsbin.com/kitotoyise/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: `onFocus="startCalc();"` Where's this function? And in your stopCalc function where is `interval` coming from in `clearInterval(interval)`?

Answer (score 0):

need to use getElementById for the form so you access the elements within it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calc(){
    var form = document.getElementById('autoSumForm')
    one = form.firstBox.value;
    two = form.secondBox.value;
    three = form.thirdBox.value;
    form.fourthBox.value = ((((two) * (two)) * 0.25) / (((three) / 100) * ((three) / 100)) / ( 1 + (((two) * (two)) * 0.25) / (((three) / 100) * ((three) / 100) * (one))));
}
</script>
```